# iCal Eventstore - successful function on completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, ekeventstore

I have the following function to add a dynamic date to Ical -

```
-(void)AddToIcal{
    EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) { return; }
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];


        event.title = self.booked.bookingTitle;
        event.startDate = self.booked.bookingDate;

        event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60];  //set 1 hour meeting
        [event setCalendar:[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent  commit:YES error:&err];
        NSString *savedEventId = event.eventIdentifier;  //this is so you can access this event later
    }];

}
```

Does anyone know how I could show a stored / not stored message when the ad event function is complete?

Comment: Do you mean you need to verify that the event is in-fact saved, and display an alert to the user?

Answer (score 0):

what about changing

```
[store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
```

to

```
if (![store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err]) {
  NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error saving event: %@", error.localizedDescription]);
} else {
  NSLog(@"Successfully saved event.");
}
```

You could as well do something different than writing to `NSLog`, like use an `UIAlertView` or such.

Also you may have a look a the `Return Value` section of the [saveEvent:span:commit:error](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/saveEvent:span:commit:error:)  Apple documentation.

It says:

> Return Value
>
> If successful, YES; otherwise, NO. Also returns NO if event does not need to be saved because it has not been modified.